# NotImplementedException in (NetNative)NetworkInterface.GetNetworkInterfaces() Win IoT Core 14393

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10

I'm trying to run some code on Windows IoT Core that uses DotNetty and 
I've run into the following exception:

`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DotNetty.Transport.Channels.DefaultChannelId' threw an exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetNativeNetworkInterface.GetNetworkInterfaces()
   at DotNetty.Common.Internal.MacAddressUtil.GetBestAvailableMac()
   at DotNetty.Common.Internal.DefaultPlatform.DotNetty.Common.Internal.IPlatform.GetDefaultDeviceId()
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.DefaultChannelId.DefaultMachineId()
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.DefaultChannelId..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.AbstractChannel.NewId()
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.AbstractChannel..ctor(IChannel parent)
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel..ctor(IChannel parent, Socket socket)`

I have found the issue on github for `corefx` [9675](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9675) and one of the comments says

> Those particular methods are unimplemented right now. We plan to add the rest of the support later this year in an update to the System.Net.NetworkInformation package.

I got `System.Net.NetworkInformation` package v4.3.0 and when I call 
`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` directly I sadly get the `NotImplementedException` exception.

`` `System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetNativeNetworkInterface.GetNetworkInterfaces()
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() ``

**Question**

Can I make this work on `Windows IoT Core 14393`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use UWP, you need 10.0.16299.

Because this API(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) applies to .NET Standard 2.0 and minimum version support .NET Standard 2.0 is 16299. Also, you need set the **UWP app min targeting version to 16299**.

[image]

Ref: [.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)

Else, you can use .NET Core Console App or .NET Framework Console App but more versions choices:

[image]

Ref: [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_NetworkInformation_NetworkInterface_GetAllNetworkInterfaces)

Comment: Thanks for your info! You say "If you use UWP, you need 10.0.16299" as if there is another way to develop apps on IoT Core. Is there another way?

Comment: @tymtam Except UWP, Windows IoT Core also supports certain traditional Win32 app types such as Win32 Console Apps like I pointed out in my answer. You can reference "[Application Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore#application-types)".